# Uninstall a Steam game from the console

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, terminal, steam

Is it possible to uninstall a Steam game from the console?

I have tried deleting the game's folder in `.steam/steam/steamapps/common`, but the game continues to appear in the Steam library, although it fails to run.

Comment: no, just i want to include that line to a program in c++ that i am programming, and i was using system(comands here); in order to achieve deleting the folders, so i thought that could be intersting find a way to do it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This used to be possible with [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) for this (it’s packaged in Debian’s non-free repositories and in Ubuntu’s multiverse):

```
steamcmd +apps_installed +quit
```

will list all installed applications with their id, and

```
steamcmd +app_uninstall appid +quit
```

will uninstall the application matching the given id; add `-complete` before the id for a complete uninstall.

SteamCMD now appears to be limited to handling games it installed, rather than any game in the default Steam directories; it also seems to be primarily intended for managing [dedicated game servers with specific SteamCMD clients](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Dedicated_Servers_List), rather than any game available on Steam.

You can manually remove a game by deleting its directory, usually in `steamapps/common` in your Steam directory, and its manifest in `steamapps`; the main Steam client may however still consider the game to be installed.